# Is there a concrete definition/formula for finding the leading coefficient of any polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, definition

Is there a concrete definition that tells one the leading coefficient of any polynomial? Using logic, I derived this formula:

$$ a=\frac{\frac{d^p}{dx^p}f(x)}{p!}$$

where $f(x)$ is a polynomial, $p$ is the power of the polynomial, and $a$ is the leading coefficient, but I have a feeling this isn't what I'm looking for, as I feel I'm missing some sort of major flaw. So, what is this concrete definition of the leading coefficient of any polynomial?

Also, I apologize if I'm using terminology incorrectly and making things confusing.

Comment: So you do know the power beforehand?

Comment: @Vim Yes, as there are already definitions for computing the power of any polynomial, but if there is a definition that does not utilize the power, then I would be glad if you could show that.

Comment: As far as I know there doesn't seem to be a universally-known "computational" definition (if this's what you mean) of the leading coefficient. To be honest I think both yours and ajotatxe's answer are quite practical...

Comment: @Vim I am looking for a universally known one, but as I can see now, that doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

This one also works:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^p}$$

Comment: Though you did provide great information, you didn't exactly answer my question. It would be preferred if you had posted this as a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Subtle point: a *polynomial* isn't the same than a *polynomial function*. In algebra, a polynomial is an *expresssion* $a_nx^n+\cdots+a_0$ with the $a_i$ in some field/ring/... If $a_n\ne 0$, then *by definition* $a_n$ is the leading coefficient. In a field of characteristic zero (like $\Bbb R$) different polynomials give different polynomial functions, but in positive characteristic, different polynomials can give the same polynomial function.

Your formula is true even in the algebraic case (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_derivative), but in the algebraic case the coefficients *are known beforehand*.

Comment: Well, a polynomial function is $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$ which, as far as I'm concerned, is a polynomial that's just defined as a function. I understand what you mean, but that doesn't really matter here since I'm speaking so generally. Thanks for the heads up though.